# Rotar una imagen y guardar sin deformarse en c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Quiero rotar una imagen (jpg, png, tif, bmp) de tipo BitmapSource y guardarla. El método que he implementado lo hace, pero el problema está que al guardarla, la imagen pierde calidad debido a la compresión y yo necesito que la imagen se mantenga con la misma calidad.

```
private void SaveImage() {
    BitmapImage bmp = (Picture.Source as BitmapImage);
    MemoryStream mbmp = new MemoryStream(ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(bmp));
    System.Drawing.Image bitmap = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(mbmp);
    bitmap.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
    bitmap.Save(Images[Index].Valor, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp);
}

public static byte[] ConvertBitmapSourceToByteArray(BitmapSource image) {
    byte[] data;
    BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        encoder.Save(ms);
        data = ms.ToArray();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Has probado a cambiar el formato de imagen de `MemoryBmp`a `Bmp` o `Png` por ejemplo?

Comment: Si pero haciendo esto cambiaría el formato de la imagen original y no quiero eso. Revisando algunas bibliografias me di cuenta que la deformación de los pixeles siempre va a estar, pero viendo como rotan las imagenes algunos programas vi que no se deforman tanto y que incluso el tamaño del archivo solo sufre cambios en la primera rotación, luego se mantiene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno ahora las imágenes no se deforman a la vista:

```
private void Rotate(Rotation rotate) {
    BitmapImage bmp = (Picture.Source as BitmapImage);
    System.Drawing.Image bitmap = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(bmp.StreamSource);
    bitmap.RotateFlip(rotate == Rotation.Rotate90 ?
        System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY : rotate == Rotation.Rotate270 ?
        System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipXY : rotate == Rotation.Rotate180 ?
        System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipXY : System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipXY);
    MemoryStream mbitmap = new MemoryStream();
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

    bitmap.Save(Images[Index].Valor, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.MemoryBmp);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Images[Index].Valor, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        byte[] file = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(file, 0, file.Length);
        image = ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(file);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
    }
}

public static BitmapImage ConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(Byte[] bytes) {
    var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.EndInit();
    return image;
}
```